# print to output at specific location on line in c++

Tags: c++, string, printing

I am trying to print to a uniform position in a line after printing out a header.  here's an example:

```
PHRASE                 TYPE
"hello there"       => greeting
"yo"                => greeting
"where are you?"    => question
"It's 3:00"         => statement
"Wow!"              => exclamation
```

Assume each of these are stored in a `std::map<string, string>`, where key = phrase and value = type.   My issue is that simply using tabs is dependent on the console or text editor that I view the output in.  If the tab width is too small I won't know for sure where it will be printed.  I have tried using `setw`, but that only prints the separator ("=>") a fixed distance from the end of the phrase.  Is there a simple way to do this?

**NOTE** Assume for now that we just always know that the phrase will not be longer than, say, 16 characters.  We don't need to account for what to do if it is.

Comment: `setw` indeed is your friend here. Can you post your code? Maybe you put it at a wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) and [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw):

```
std::cout << std::left; // This is "sticky", but setw is not.
std::cout << std::setw(16) << phrase << " => " << type << "\n";
```

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
    m["hello there"]    = "greeting";
    m["where are you?"] = "question";

    std::cout << std::left;

    for (std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator i = m.begin();
         i != m.end();
         i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(16)
                  << std::string("\"" + i->first + "\"")
                  << " => "
                  << i->second
                  << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
"hello there"    => greeting
"where are you?" => question
```

See http://ideone.com/JTv6na for demo.

Comment: You omitted the quotes, but this solution does not account for them. If you added the quotes into this solution, the closing quote would be placed after the padding spaces.

Comment: You are using `setw(16)` but it should be `setw(18)` since the quotes count against your length now.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, OK. I will leave that for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("\"%s\"%*c => %s", 
    it->first.c_str(), 
    std::max(0, 16 - it->first.size()),
    ' ',
    it->second.c_str());`
```

The same idea as Peter's solution, but puts the padding *outside* the quotes. It uses `%c` with a length argument to insert padding.

Comment: For the padding you could have done `%*c` and give `16 - it->first.size(), ' '` or `%*s` and `..., ""`. This way you wouldn't have a hard cap on your padding and you don't need an extra string for it.

Comment: Good idea, I've switched to the `%*c` approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not adverse to C-style printing, `printf` is great for this sort of thing, and much more readable:

```
printf("\"%16s\" => %s\n", it->first.c_str(), it->second.c_str());
```

There's nothing wrong with using printf and friends in a C++ program, just be careful mixing iostreams and stdio.  You can always sprintf into a buffer, then output that with iostreams.

Comment: This will put the closing quote after the padding spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this function useful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void printRightPadded(std::ostream &stream,const std::string &s,size_t width)
{
  std::ios::fmtflags old_flags = stream.setf(std::ios::left);
  stream << std::setw(width) << s;
  stream.flags(old_flags);
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
void
  printKeyAndValue(
    std::ostream &stream,
    const std::string &key,
    const std::string &value
  )
{
  printRightPadded(stream,"\"" + key + "\"",18);
  stream << " => " << value << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can't work out with setw, a simple alternative to try is to patch all phrase with spaces so that they are all 16 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find the C-style printing more readable for formatted printing. Using `printf` you could also handle the column width using the `*` formatter.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    printf("%-*s%-*s\n", 10, "Hello", 10, "World");
    printf("%-*s%-*s\n", 15, "Hello", 15, "World");  

    // in the above, '-' left aligns the field
    // '*' denotes that the field width is a parameter specified later
    // ensure that the width is specified before what it is used to print  
}
```

Output

```
Hello     World     
Hello          World
```

Comment: Perhaps `%-*s=> %s` would better replicate what the user wants.

Comment: @Shahbaz I mentioned that, but you are right, I should probably make it more explicitly visible.